# upstart logs missing

Tags: upstart, syslog

I have been trying (unsuccessfully) to automate a script (or at least the actions contained within) that I run in Terminal each time a reboot my system, to enable the WiFi.

I have been following as many of the responses on this forum as to how to autommate actions at startup as I can and focused most of my attention around using upstart. Since there is no apparent sign that my script (or any derivation I can come up with) has run I decided I needed to turn debug logging on in initctl and watch what happens with my "script" when events get triggered. Low and behold, initctl is not writing to /var/log/syslog.

Where is it writing to and/or why is it not writing there? I have a directory in /var/log called upstart but all that is in that directory is archive files. For the record I'm running 13.04 with the latest updates applied.

Comment: How you call your script and what it's content?

Comment: @Braiam I'm having the same problem with a Ubuntu 13.10 system. It works as expected on a Ubuntu 12.04 system. [**Here**](http://serverfault.com/questions/571798/cannot-find-upstart-logs-in-syslog-despite-a-log-priority-of-debug-ubuntu-13-04) is another example of somebody who seems to be having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted an answer to Bradd's question: https://askubuntu.com/a/490900/297973. Long story short, you may need to add `$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on` to rsyslogd's config.